# How to get the data inside object: list, data

Tags: php, curl

Help, I cant find the solution here, Searching is no help so I decided to post a question here.

```
<?php
function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

 $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
     $output = json_encode($output,true);
     $output = json_decode($output,true);
     return $output;
}

$a = httpGet("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers");

echo'<pre>';
print_r($a);

?>
```

My question is how to get the ID?
I want to get the ID, only. How can I access it? 
I also feel that their is something wrong with my code, please help and correct it.

```
{
"object": "list",
"data": [
  {
    "id": "cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa",
    "object": "customer",
    "account_balance": 0,
    "created": 1490067687,
    "currency": null,
    "default_source": null,
    "delinquent": false,
    "description": null,
    "discount": null,
    "email": "hello@gmail.com",
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {},
    "shipping": null,
    "sources": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 0,
      "url": "/v1/customers/cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa/sources"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 0,
      "url": "/v1/customers/cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa/subscriptions"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cus_AKIP3muBIL95H0",
    "object": "customer",
    "account_balance": 0,
    "created": 1490067468,
    "currency": null,
    "default_source": null,
    "delinquent": false,
    "description": null,
    "discount": null,
    "email": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {},
    "shipping": null,
    "sources": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 0,
      "url": "/v1/customers/cus_AKIP3muBIL95H0/sources"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 0,
      "url": "/v1/customers/cus_AKIP3muBIL95H0/subscriptions"
    }
  },
```

after removing json_encode($output,true); the result is

```
Array
(
    [object] => list
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa
                    [object] => customer
                    [account_balance] => 0
                    [created] => 1490067687
                    [currency] => 
                    [default_source] => 
                    [delinquent] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [discount] => 
                    [email] => hello@gmail.com
                    [livemode] => 
                    [metadata] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [shipping] => 
                    [sources] => Array
                        (
                            [object] => list
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [has_more] => 
                            [total_count] => 0
                            [url] => /v1/customers/cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa/sources
                        )

                    [subscriptions] => Array
                        (
                            [object] => list
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [has_more] => 
                            [total_count] => 0
                            [url] => /v1/customers/cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa/subscriptions
                        )

                )
```

Comment: for getting Id use `echo $a["data"][0][id];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acces your id like this...

```
function httpGet($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // $output = json_decode($output,true); only necessary if the result of $output is a json encoded array
    return $output;
}

$array = httpGet("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers");

for($i = 0; $i < count($array["data"]); $++){

    echo $array["data"][$i]["id"] . "\r\n";

}
```

Comment: Im using the data as php.

Comment: The result is shown on my post, below my codes, after print_r($a).

Comment: That shows me the results after you have encoded and then decided it. I would like to see the results of $output before you did this

Comment: Your json_ functions may not even be necessary

Comment: The result without json function

Comment: {
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa",
      "object": "customer",
      "account_balance": 0,
      "created": 1490067687,
      "currency": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "delinquent": false,
      "description": null,
      "discount": null,
      "email": "hello@gmail.com",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {},
      "shipping": null,

Comment: "sources": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/customers/cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa/sources"
      },
      "subscriptions": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/customers/cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa/subscriptions"
      }
    },

Comment: where am i looking for the results? did you update the original?

Comment: Wait ill update it, I remove json_encode and the result is much better.

Comment: alright so you can lose the json_ encode and keep the decode. the encode is not necessary as it's already a json array

Comment: the json decode with the true parameter will give you an associative array. i will update my answer on how to access the data.

Comment: updated my answer... if the result of $output IS in fact a json array then uncomment the json_decode. otherwise this should work.

Comment: The result is cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMacus_AKIP3muBIL95H0cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyKcus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxBcus_AKHxuw8UvlwH8vcus_AKHx6iyvJJOwWecus_AK03kmAOGCziJ8 exactly 7 customer

Comment: to separate each ID I try 
$id .= $a["id"];
$id .=',';

 the result is
cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa,cus_AKIP3muBIL95H0,cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyK,cus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxB,cus_AKHxuw8UvlwH8v,cus_AKHx6iyvJJOwWe,cus_AK03kmAOGCziJ8,

Ill use explode here.
Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: you have more than one item in the data.... each item has an id.... so the foreach loops through each of the itema and gives you the id for that item

Comment: so if you just want to echo them out on individual lines i have updated my answer for you

Comment: By the way I include  $output = json_decode($output,true); to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome glad i could help... don't forget to vote on my answer ;-)

Comment: The result of the updated code duplicates the id, cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMacus_AKIP3muBIL95H0 cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMacus_AKIP3muBIL95H0cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyK cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMacus_AKIP3muBIL95H0cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyKcus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxB cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMacus_AKIP3muBIL95H0cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyKcus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxBcus_AKHxuw8UvlwH8v cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMacus_AKIP3muBIL95H0cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyKcus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxBcus_AKHxuw8UvlwH8vcus_AKHx6iyvJJOwWe cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMacus_AKIP3muBIL95H0cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyKcus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxBcus_AKHxuw8UvlwH8vcus_AKHx6iyvJJOwWecus_AK03kmAOGCziJ8

Comment: Ill stick with 
$id .= $a["id"];
$id .=",";

Then use explode. Thanks again!!